# What Azure Table IOPS limitations exist with the different Web App (or function) sizes?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I'm looking at [high scale Azure table operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17955557/328397), and I am looking for documentation that describes the maxIOPS to expect from Azure instance sizes for Azure Web App, Function, etc.

The Web Roles and corresponding limitation is well documented.  For example see this comment in the linked question

> so, we ran our tests on different instance sizes and yes that makes a huge difference. at medium we get around 1200 writes per second, on extra large we get around 7200. We are looking at building a distributed read/write controller possibly using the dcache as the middle man. – JTtheGeek Aug 9 '13 at 22:39

**Question**

- What is the corresponding limitation for the Web Apps (logic, mobile, etc) and Azure Table IOPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets) that `total Request Rate (assuming 1 KB object size) per storage account Up to 20,000 IOPS, entities per second, or messages per second`. We also can get the VM Max IOPS limitations from the Azure [VM size document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-sizes?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json).  Web Apps are based on service plan, in the service plan we could choose different price tiers that have different VM sizes. It maybe could use for reference. More Azure limitation please refer to [Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).

[image]