# How to insert thousands of rows to Azure Storage Table with App Function using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am trying to write Azure App Function using Python
where I am creating a simple Azure Storage Table and
saving like up to 10000 rows.

I have tried to create entity by entity by using

```
from azure.data.tables import TableClient, TableTransactionError
...
table_client.create_entity({...})
```

It works but it is slow.

Then I tried to use

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor
```

which speed up entire process quite a lot but you CANNOT use it in **Azure app Function from obvious** reasons.

I also tried to use

```
table_client.upsert_entity(i)
...

table_client.submit_transaction(operations)
```

but it is again slow.

Finally I tried

```
# Create a new batch
batch = TableBatch()

# Count how many items are stored in the batch
inBatch = 0

# Loop over all the data we want to insert
for x in dataToStore:
    
    # Insert the entity into the batch
    batch.insert_entity({
        'PartitionKey': 'PARTITION1',
        'RowKey': str(x['rowkey']),
        'someKey': x['someValue'],
        'someOtherKey': x['someOtherValue']
    })
    
    # Increment the batch item counter
    inBatch += 1
    
    # We can only send batches with up to 100 records
    if inBatch > 99:
        # Commit the batch (send to Azure)
        table_service.commit_batch('tablename', batch)
        
        # Reset the batch so it doesn't contain any old items
        batch = TableBatch()
        inBatch = 0
```

But this is quite slow and not durable at all.,

Azure Storage table claims that you can save huge amount of data quickly.

Anyone knows how?

Comment: take a look on this thread it may help you find the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955557/painfully-slow-azure-table-insert-and-delete-batch-operations

Comment: Thanks @ThiagoCustodio but I would need to see an example in Python :/

Answer (score 4):

A few observations. You haven't mentioned how long your tests actually took. That would have been useful.

Usually when writing to table storage you would choose a partition id which is well distributed. However, in your example, you are using the same partition id = 'PARTITION1'. In this case, you can try using the Cosmos table storage SDK to batch up your entities and load them in a go. You can only use the batching in Cosmos table storage SDK if all entities in your batch have the same partition key.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmosdb-table/azure.cosmosdb.table.tablebatch.tablebatch?view=azure-python) states that you can load upto 100 entities or 4MB which ever is met first.

I ran a quick test using the Cosmos table python SDK and batch 50 entities in a go. I was able to load 1000 entities in around 35s. A 10000 entity load took me 4:55. I'm not sure if this suits your requirements or you were expecting something faster. Also please note, that my example entity is slightly larger in size that yours. Below is my code and this looks fairly similar to yours. This should be fairly easy to put into an Azure function.

```
#USING COSMOS TABLE STORAGE API
from azure.cosmosdb.table import TableService, TableBatch
from datetime import datetime
from random import randrange
import random
import names
import json
from datetime import timedelta
import uuid


acc_name = '<storageacct_name>'
acc_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
table_name='xxxxxxx'
Number_of_docs = 10000
d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2008 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
d2 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2009 4:50 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

service = TableService(account_name=acc_name, 
                       account_key=acc_key)

def random_date(start, end):
    """
    This function will return a random datetime between two datetime 
    objects.
    """
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

def create_entity(id):
    my_entity = {"PartitionKey" : "PARTITION1",
                "RowKey" : str(id),
                "employee_id" : str(id),
                "first_name" : names.get_first_name(),
                "last_name" : names.get_last_name(),
                "regn_no" : "TEST00000000"+ str(id),
                "start_date" : random_date(d1,d2),
                "salary" : random.randint(12000, 2000000),
                "inserted_at" : str(datetime.now())
                }
    return my_entity

starttime = datetime.utcnow()
print("Starting ingestion: ", starttime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
batch_no = 0
batch = TableBatch()
for i in range(Number_of_docs):
    i = i + 1
    batch_no = batch_no + 1
    my_entity = create_entity(i)
    batch.insert_or_merge_entity(my_entity)
    if (batch_no > 50):
        service.commit_batch(table_name, batch)
        batch_no = 0
        batch = TableBatch()
    else:      
        batch_no = batch_no + 1
    
if (batch_no > 0):
    service.commit_batch(table_name, batch)

endtime = datetime.utcnow()
print("\nrun_sample done :" + endtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
print("Time taken :" + str(endtime-starttime))
print("Number of messages :" + str(Number_of_docs))
```

**EDIT** : Apologies, I did realize that the Cosmos table SDK is being replaced by the azure data-tabes API as per [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/data-tables-readme?view=azure-python) released 3 days ago. So I have rewritten this code using the new table storage SDK and tested it again. Results are infact better. 3:55 for 10000 entities. You can find more examples on how to use this new SDK [HERE](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples).

```
#USING THE NEW TABLE STORAGE API
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
from datetime import datetime
from random import randrange
import random
import names
import json
from datetime import timedelta
import uuid


conn='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
tablename='mytable'      
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn,table_name=tablename)
Number_of_docs = 10000
d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2008 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
d2 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2009 4:50 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

def random_date(start, end):
    """
    This function will return a random datetime between two datetime 
    objects.
    """
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

def create_entity(id):
    my_entity = {"PartitionKey" : "PARTITION1",
                "RowKey" : str(id),
                "employee_id" : str(id),
                "first_name" : names.get_first_name(),
                "last_name" : names.get_last_name(),
                "regn_no" : "TEST00000000"+ str(id),
                "start_date" : random_date(d1,d2),
                "salary" : random.randint(12000, 2000000),
                "inserted_at" : str(datetime.now())
                }
    return my_entity

starttime = datetime.utcnow()
print("Starting ingestion: ", starttime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
batch_no = 0
operations = []
for i in range(Number_of_docs):
    i = i + 1
    batch_no = batch_no + 1
    my_entity = create_entity(i)
    operations.append(("upsert", my_entity))
    if (batch_no > 50):
        table_client.submit_transaction(operations)
        batch_no = 0
        operations = []
    else:      
        batch_no = batch_no + 1
    
if (batch_no > 0):
    service.commit_batch(table_name, batch)

endtime = datetime.utcnow()
print("\nrun_sample done :" + endtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
print("Time taken :" + str(endtime-starttime))
print("Number of messages :" + str(Number_of_docs))
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer but I am not using Cosmos, correct me if I am wrong but I assume I cannot use this code for Azure Storage Table.

Comment: You can use the same code for Azure table storage.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realize that the cosmos table sdk is being deprecated. I have updated my answer with an edit along with code using the new SDK.

Comment: Hi  @user2156115, Did my response answer your question? If so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes it is correct thx, I voted up but I do not see anything like "mark as correct answer"

Comment: There should be a Tick mark below the 'Down vote' arrow which is visible only to the person who asked the question.